# Change delegate

Tags: tezos-client

I have Alice and Bob both set as their own bakers, and I am trying to change this to have Bob delegate to Alice. I get an error when using **tezos-client set delegate for bob to alice**, I also tried to remove Bob's delegate, but I also get an error.
Thanks for your help!

**~$ tezos-client get delegate for alice**

```
Warning:

             This is NOT the Tezos Mainnet.

       Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.

tz1TB74aPtw2cAeuMaQeaSeLXFrKEXTWd4ts (known as alice)
```

**~$ tezos-client get delegate for bob**

```
Warning:

             This is NOT the Tezos Mainnet.

       Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.

tz1VU1Vrpn33kJf9BVt8EB4jQZgQRuegnHEQ (known as bob)
```

**~$ tezos-client set delegate for bob to alice**

```
Warning:

             This is NOT the Tezos Mainnet.

       Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.

Node is bootstrapped.
This simulation failed:
  Manager signed operations:
    From: tz1VU1Vrpn33kJf9BVt8EB4jQZgQRuegnHEQ
    Fee to the baker: ꜩ0
    Expected counter: 1397277
    Gas limit: 1040000
    Storage limit: 0 bytes
    Delegation:
      Contract: tz1VU1Vrpn33kJf9BVt8EB4jQZgQRuegnHEQ
      To: tz1TB74aPtw2cAeuMaQeaSeLXFrKEXTWd4ts
      This operation FAILED.

Error:
  Delegate deletion is forbidden (tz1VU1Vrpn33kJf9BVt8EB4jQZgQRuegnHEQ)
```

**~$ tezos-client withdraw delegate from bob**

```
Warning:

             This is NOT the Tezos Mainnet.

       Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.

Node is bootstrapped.
This simulation failed:
  Manager signed operations:
   From: tz1VU1Vrpn33kJf9BVt8EB4jQZgQRuegnHEQ
   Fee to the baker: ꜩ0
   Expected counter: 1397277
   Gas limit: 1040000
   Storage limit: 0 bytes
   Delegation:
     Contract: tz1VU1Vrpn33kJf9BVt8EB4jQZgQRuegnHEQ
     To: nobody
     This operation FAILED.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed once an address is registered as a baker its delegate must be itself and cannot change anymore. Bob can however transfer its unfrozen tokens to another address (one that is not registered as a baker) and delegate to Alice from there.